# Pyspark reading pickled files

Tags: python, apache-spark

My data are available as sets of python 3 pickled files. Most of them are serialization of pandas data frames.

I'd like to start using spark because I need more memory and CPU that one computer can have. Also, I'll use HDFS for distributed storage.

As a beginner, I didn't found relevant information explaining how to use pickle files as input file.

Does it exists? If not, are there any workaround?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This question belongs on stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on SO

Comment: Indeed, you are both right. I've tried to close is for that reason, but I didn't succeed

Comment: @eliasah True: the entry you mention is this one, transferred to another forum. Please see previous comments.

Comment: If the answer to that question answers this question too, would you care to delete this one please ?

Comment: As shown in the comments before, I didn't found how to delete this.